# Is it possible to combine two input types into one ArcGIS Geoprocessing Tool for web?

Tags: geoprocessing, arcgis-web-appbuilder

I'm working on a project where I basically need to combine the different types of input parameters into one geoprocessing widget, rather than have multiple widgets for the different input types.  Is this possible?

For example, one widget has an input where the user simply clicks a point on a map and outputs a single circle buffer.  another has an input where the user selects the input from a dropdown box and outputs a different buffer.

Comment: do you have 2 geoprocessing services?

Comment: I do, but I only need one.

Comment: Well in your example, it sounds like 1 gp service has an input feature set and the other has a list of layers (those layers are specific to the service and the service knows where that data is). If a gp service is setup to pick from a list of layers, you cant pass in a feature set point. Its one or the other. So you'd need 2 GP Services.  You could write a custom widget that is 1 control but based on how the user selects the input it calls 1 service or another in the back end